# discord.py rewrite: How do i make a interaction not expire after 15 minutes

Tags: discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a /giveaway command for my discord bot, but when the user clicks the "join giveaway" button after 15 mins (after the giveaway was created)it says "Application Didn't Respond"

Is there any way to bypass/solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button has a default timeout of 200 seconds, and you can bypass that with timeout=none. (Discord.py latest version)

```
Button(label='No timeout', timeout=None)
```